# Will having dozens of inactive logins hurt performance

Tags: linux, users, cluster

I work on a cluster shared with ~20 users, many of them operating remotely. It's quite common to open the login node, type `users` and see ~100 users listed, mostly the same user logged in multiple times. The cpu use from all these logins is negligible, as is the memory use, but somehow it just *seems wrong*. The login node is also often rather sluggish, so while it's difficult to dissociate this from network latency I wonder if it's related.

Will these logins somehow slow down interactive sessions on the remote machine in ways that won't show up when I run `top` (i.e. even if they aren't consuming much memory / cpu)?

Comment: Whose performance?

Comment: I think he means the remote machine.If the CPU and memory use is negligible, I think there is no need to wory...and it is wrong, but you can't change user stupidity ;)

Comment: Hopefully I sharpened the question a bit: I'm running `top` and everything "looks ok" but I wonder if it's causing problems behind the scenes.

Comment: No, remember that Unix was designed to be multi-user, so this is completely fine and shouldn't impact performance in any noticeable way. You Q is still overly vague, but I understand what you're asking and answered you regardless 8-). You need to make it more specific in "how" these would "bog" down the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @slm, hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: @Shep makes more sense to me now, anyway, thank you. You know, though, if a user's logged in multiple times that would indicate - to me at least - multiple ptys - and that can affect performance if they're zombied and simply aren't dying. There is a process limit.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, since memory and CPU usage are negligible as you said, idle users won't hurt anyone.  If you still want to get rid of them, you could automatically hunt down idle users and kick them off, either by e.g. a shell script you call in regular intervals via `cron`, or by setting

```
ClientAliveInterval 1800
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  But respect the actual description of these parameters in `sshd_config(8)`, though, so you don't expect too much:  These options only end a session if the server is actually not receiving *any* data from the user (i.e. they have an idle shell opened, that doesn't do anything).  If your users idle with e.g. `top` running, which steadily updates its display and thus communicates over the connection, the approach wouldn't work (but you could actually argue if having a long-running process displaying any kind of information is actually being idle anyways).